# Excel - Why does INDEX(<array>,0) return <array>?

Tags: excel, indexing

I am using a formula with `INDEX`, and `IFERROR` to handle those cases where the index number is out of the range of the array that index is searching.

Simplified formula I'm using

```
= IFERROR(INDEX({"A","B","C"},A1),"no match")
```

As expected, if `A1` is 1, the formula returns `A`, if `A1` is 2, the formula returns `B`, and if `A1` is 3, the formula returns `C`. And any other value in `A1` (e.g. 5) would return `no match` *except* if `A1` is 0. In that case, the formula returns the original array, that being `{"A","B","C"}`.

This actually messes up my plan, as I now need extra checking because I want to return `no match` if `A1` is 0, but I don't need help doing this.

My question is: Is there any practical application of `INDEX(<array>,0)`? If it just returns `<array>`, then it just seems superfluous, but the fact that this exists makes me believe there is a reason for it.

Comment: Looking at the help file for `INDEX` it says _If you set row_num or column_num to 0 (zero), INDEX returns the array of values for the entire column or row, respectively._, so looks like it's by design.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Ah, ok, that makes sense and is useful to return entire row or column in a matrix. Thank you.

Comment: I had a look around for why the decision was made to set like that, but afraid I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It makes sense to give an option to return the entire row or column, just unfortunate they chose to do it with a `0` because of what I stated above. Now extra checks need to be taken into account to intentionally change this `0` to something else. If only to return the full row, it was something like `INDEX(<array>,"full")` or something then this would have been a non-issue. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, would've made life much easier to make have a specific option for the whole array.  Best I could think of as a replacement would be along the lines of:  `=IFERROR(INDEX({"A","B","C"},IF($A$1<1,-1,$A$1)),"no match")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks, unfortunately that isn't ideal considering `A1` was just a simplified example but in my case, `A1` is replaced with a much longer expression. There are methods to avoid typing it twice, again just unfortunate that a workaround is needed because of this.